# How to create my own dashboard in Azure Devops from csv data

Tags: azure, devops

I have data in the CSV file, I wanted to create a visualization from that data in Azure DevOps. so that I can visualize the data in the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one or more **widgets** or **charts** to your dashboard, which are customizable and configurable. Creating Azure DevOps dashboards out of CSV data is not supported.

Submit your suggestion on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) for Azure DevOps if you think it can benefit others in the Community as well.